# if statement nested in for statement won't work

Tags: c++, if-statement, nested

I've searched all over the internet, but I can't find an answer to my problem anywhere.  I'm trying to write a program that will find the inverse of a 3x3 matrix and I'm trying to set up the matrix of minors.

Code(it's not all the code only the part that doesn't work):

```
for (int d = 0; d < rows; d++)  /** d is the row of the matrix of minors **/
{
    for (int m = 0; m < cols; m++) /** m is the column of matrix of minors **/
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) /** i is the row of the main martix **/
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) /** j is the column of the main matrix**/
            (d == i || m == j)? dothis = false : dothis = true;
                    /** This is to determin if the number at postion (i,j) is part
                      of the determent for the matrix of minors.  For postion (d,m)
                      of the matrix of minors, row d and colum m of the main matrix
                      are crossed out.**/

                if (dothis == 'true')
                {

                    /** postions for the determent matrix **/

                    detmin.set(mrtx.access(i,j), I, J);
                    /** this will set the determent matrix with the numbers
                      remaining from the cross-out prosecess. **/

                    I++;
                    J++;
                }

            }
        }

        detmin.display(3, 3); /** This makes sure the program did the 
                                if statement **/
        minor.set(detmin.twodert(), d, m);
        /** takes the determent of the determent matrix and puts it
          into the matrix of minors at posstion (d,m) **/

        cout << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

The program complies fine, but when I go to run it, the program displays a 3x3 matrix of zeros.  I think that the inner most if statements are not being recognized by the program and I have no idea why.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?

**Edit**  The code now looks like it does above and all loops are running.  It still doesn't do what I want it to, but I have made progress.  Thanks.

Comment: if (dothis == 'true')... interesting :)

Comment: did you mean `if(dothis == true)`?

Comment: your fourth loop will not execute with "for (int j = 0; j < 0; j++)", also the dothis == 'true' is really weird (shouldn't compile), I think the compiler compiles it only because the entire inner-most loop will never execute because of the bounds and thus, the compiler just skips it.

Comment: Fix up the code, for (int j = 0; j < 0; j++) will not iterate, j will never be lower than 0.

Comment: I guess you should get an warning about conversion from int to string or smth like that :D . 'true' is a a string, but true = 1, the string does not

Comment: Even if you ever get it to work, it doesn't seem terribly efficient. Are you doing this for production use or is it a homework exercise?

Comment: @Cristy 'true' is a character literal (type int) not a string (type const char *).

Comment: So I've fixed the 4th loop to (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) and that's now running.  I also fixed if (dothis == true).  But the if statement still won't work.  @ David - this is a homework exercise.

Comment: @visitjoan: update the code in your question above so that it matches the code that you have now with, i.e. with the various fixes suggested already in place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fourth nested loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < 0; j++)
```

never executes. Look at the condition...

Answer (score 1):

Er, don't you mean `if (dothis)`?

Answer (score 1):

'true' is incorrect.

The for(int j = 0; j < 0; j++) block won't be executed since j is zero.
Also, why do you increment in the IF block?

```
I++;
J++;
```

These values are reset to 0 the next time that block is reached.

Answer (score 1):

1. dothis == 'true'. Compiles under C++, but is always FALSE ('true' is integer constant 0x74727565 and boolean equals 0 (false) or 1 (true)).
2. You never set dothis = true.
3. As already mentioned, the innermost loop is never executed.

Comment: `'true'` is a integer constant equal to `0x74727565` because if we go through each character's ascii value we get: `t = 0x74` (116), `r = 0x72` (114), `u = 0x75` (117), `e = 0x65` (101). Putting them all together we get `0x74727565`.

Comment: *boolean equals 0 (false) or 1 (true))* Yeah, that's wrong.  If that were true you wouldn't be able to write things like `if(somePointer) { }` (well, you could, but it would only work if the value of the pointer was 0x1).  0 evaluates to false and non-zero evaluates to true.  The macro TRUE is typically set to 1, but that isn't relevant when we are talking about how conditionals are evaluated. -1

Comment: @Ed: What? I'd up-vote if I wasn't out of votes. Booleans are either `true` or `false`, which convert to 1 or 0, respectively. There is no "the macro `TRUE`" in the language, so you're talking nonsense there. What exactly are you objecting to?

Comment: Well yes, TRUE and FALSE are not in the language spec, but any non-zero value will evaluate to true.  I was assuming he got the idea that true is 1 from the macro.

Comment: @Ed: `true` is 1 by definition. Any non-zero value is true because that's how the integer-to-bool conversion is defined. Conditionals take a `bool`, so that conversion takes place.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right.  I had a brain fart there.  The check will be for `doThis == 0x74727565`, i.e., `if( 1 == 0x74727565)`, thus always false.  Downvote removed and replaced with an upvote since the selected answer doesn't touch on all of the problems in that code.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing braces in your innermost loop, so only the `dothis` assignment runs in the loop. However, that assignment is unnecessary because its value is only used once (and incorrectly -- it should be compared to `true`, not `"true"`).

Here's a better way to write it:

```
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) /** j is the column of the main matrix**/
            {
                    /** This is to determin if the number at postion (i,j) is part
                      of the determent for the matrix of minors.  For postion (d,m)
                      of the matrix of minors, row d and colum m of the main matrix
                      are crossed out.**/

                if (d == i || m == j)
                {

                    /** postions for the determent matrix **/

                    detmin.set(mrtx.access(i,j), I, J);
                    /** this will set the determent matrix with the numbers
                      remaining from the cross-out prosecess. **/

                    I++;
                    J++;
                }
            }
        }
```